Не подключается модуль suds.client
Для использования API нужно выполнить from suds.client import Client
Почитал, что для этого нужен пакет suds-jurko, с бубном установил его в виртуальное окружение.
Но по какой-то причине модуль не подключается (VS Code показывает что модуль не найден).
Вот установленные модули:
(venv)
User@DESKTOP-111 MINGW64 /c/Dev/
$ pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- --------
imutils               0.5.4   
numpy                 1.26.2  
opencv-contrib-python 4.8.1.78
opencv-python         4.8.1.78
pip                   24.0    
setuptools            57.0.0  
suds-jurko            0.6

Вот скрин соообщения в VS Code:

Подскажите как можно решить вопрос.

Окружение в vsc то выбрали, куда библиотеку ставили?

Ну я да. Сделал отдельную папку "test", в ней есть те пакеты которые были выше. Потом в консоли внутри VS Code активировал виртуальное окружение командой $ source venv/Scripts/activate
